# Verilog: Altenative way for indexing signal on the LHS

Tags: indexing, verilog, xilinx, hdl, xilinx-ise

I'm using Xilinx that uses XST to synthesize my design. I ran into trouble when I write something like `someReg[offest*index+:constant] <= someOtherReg;`. The error given is 'Variable index is not supported in signal.' What I've gathered after searching online is that indexing a signal that is on the left hand side is not supported by XST synthesis tool.

---

What I'm wondering is how to realize that logic of indexing the signal without using that syntax. In the example below I'm creating a Matrix multiplier that reuses a 'rowByColumn' multiplier.

---

Basically at every rising clock edge I'm loading new values to the input of the 'rowByColumn' multiplier and at the next rising clock edge I'm saving the result at a new register. Saving the result at a new register is the main problem I have.

---

Here is the code that gives the error. Could you give suggestions on ways to solve or work around the problem.

```
module MatrixSeq(clk,A,B,C);
    // param
    parameter WIDTH = 32;
    parameter ROW_A  = 2;
    parameter COL_A  = 2;
    parameter ROW_B  = 2;
    parameter COL_B  = 2;
    //ports
    input clk;
    input [WIDTH*COL_A*ROW_A-1:0] A;
    input [WIDTH*COL_B*ROW_B-1:0] B;
    output [WIDTH*ROW_A*COL_B-1:0] C;

    // inputs to rowBycol 
    reg signed [WIDTH*COL_A-1:0] currentRowA;
    reg signed [WIDTH*ROW_B-1:0] currentColB;
    reg signed [WIDTH-1:0] rowByColOut;
    wire signed [WIDTH-1:0] rowByColOutWire; // wire to connet to rowByColOut

    // A,B matrix holders
    reg signed [WIDTH*COL_A*ROW_A-1:0] AsigHolder;
    reg signed [WIDTH*COL_B*ROW_B-1:0] BsigHolder;
    reg signed [WIDTH*ROW_A*ROW_B-1:0] CsigHolder; // C = A*B

    // reg signed [WIDTH-1:0] count;
    integer idxA = 0;       // iterates through the rows of A
    integer idxB = 0;       // iterates through the 'rows' of B

    // Indexing Syntax:
    //  signalAdd[some_expression +: some_range];
    //  Resolves to
    //  signalAdd[some_expression + (some_range - 1) : some_expression];

    always @(posedge clk) begin     // assume we have the transpose of matrix B
        currentRowA <= AsigHolder[WIDTH*COL_A*idxA+:WIDTH*COL_A];
        currentColB <= BsigHolder[WIDTH*COL_B+idxB+:WIDTH*COL_B];
        CsigHolder[WIDTH*(idxA*ROW_A+idxB)+:WIDTH] <= rowByColOut;  // Error: 'Variable index is not supported in signal.'
        idxB <= idxB +1;
        if(idxB == ROW_B) begin     // multiply each row of A with every 'row' B
            idxA <= idxA + 1;
            idxB <= 0;
        end else if(idxA == ROW_A) begin
            idxA <= 0;
            idxB <= 0;
        end
    end
    assign rowByColOutWire = rowByColOut;
    rowBycol rowMultColumn (.CLK(clk), .a(currentRowA), .b(currentColB), .y(rowByColOutWire));  // row by column multiplier
    assign C = CsigHolder;

endmodule
```

Just to be clear the problem is the third line inside the always block that gives the error 'Variable index is not supported in signal.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If XST doesn't support part-select (`+:`/`-:`) and you cannot upgrade to something complaint with IEEE Std 1364-2001, then you will need to do it the 1995 method; bit assignment:

```
for(bit_idx = 0; bit_idx < WIDTH*COL_A; bit_idx=bit_idx+1) begin
  currentRowA[idx] <= AsigHolder[WIDTH*COL_A*idxA + bit_idx];
end
```

Or two dimensional arrays:

```
reg signed [WIDTH*COL_A-1:0] AsigHolder [0:ROW_A-1];
...

always @(posedge clk) begin     // assume we have the transpose of matrix B
  currentRowA <= AsigHolder[idxA];
```

I noticed your `idxA` and `idxB` can go out of range. All registers assigned with non-blocking (`<=`) are updated after evaluation. This means `idxB==ROW_B` will be evaluated before `idxB <= idxB +1` is updated.
You should have something more like the following:

```
if (idxB < ROW_B-1) begin
  idxB <= idxB + 1;
end
else begin
  idxB <= 0;
  if (idxA < ROW_A-1) begin
    idxA <= idxA + 1;
  end
  else begin
    idxA <= 0;
  end
end
```

***Note***: by fixing the index assignments, the part-select (`+:`/`-:`) may work as the the design cannot reach an out of bound index.

Comment: Thanks for notice that `idxA` and `idxB` might get out of range. XST only complains on on this line `CsigHolder[WIDTH*(idxA*ROW_A+idxB)+:WIDTH] <= rowByColOut;` . I will try using the 'two dimensional' array and see if it sysnthesizes.

Comment: I defined CsigHolder like this `reg signed [WIDTH-1:0] CsigHolder [0:ROW_A*COL_B-1];`. XST gives an error when I try to connect the wire `C` to `CsigHolder` using the the assign statement like this `assign C = CsigHolder;`. How should I connect `C` to `CsigHolder`?